# Gulp build failing after TFS2015 update with cryptic ENOENT message

Tags: gulp, tfs-2015

After updating TFS2015 to update2 (from TFS2015), the **gulp** VSO task started to fail with the following error:

```
2016-04-25T16:18:38.8309669Z Gulp failed with error: 
D:\Services\TfsBuildAgent\_work\45c8258d\proj1\proj1.site\gulp failed. 
spawn D:\Services\TfsBuildAgent\_work\45c8258d\proj1\proj1.site\gulp ENOENT
```

It's cryptic message that doesn't tell anything, and all I did was install update2 for TFS2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be kind of bug in VSO gulp task. Namely, my gulp project has also custom folder called "gulp", which holds all the javascript files related build.

Eg it has files:

1. inject.js
2. build.js

and so on..

VSO Build task has been updated to search for gulp in the projects folder "gulp" folder. Apparently my custom folder got picked up by updated VSO task, and was causing issues with cryptic message.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Gulp/gulptask.ts (line 14)

All I did to fix my problem, is to rename folder "gulp" in proj1/proj1.site/gulp to proj1/proj1.site/gulputils.

VSO Task no longer picked up that folder.